# server control inside literal server control

Tags: asp.net

Why server control are not allowed inside literal server control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal control is not a container (ie you cannot nest elements inside it).

It is similar to a label control, its designed to display plain text/html.

Have you considered using an asp:placeholder or better yet a regular HTML DIV?

Here's a good article on the asp:Literal control.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/LiteralControlASPNET11192009223739PM/LiteralControlASPNET.aspx